# knitr and beamer presentation cannot open connection

Tags: r, knitr, beamer

In RStudio when I open a new markdown file for a pdf presentation the demo script appears. If I knit this I get the following error message:-

Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
Calls:  ...  -> patch_beamer_template -> readLines -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\noblea\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpmS8rOd\file347c4edc5edc.tex': No such file or directory
Execution halted

I have not edited the demo script at all. If I make it a pdf document rather than a presentation it produces the pdf document correctly. I am guessing it is due to something in the beamer template but how do I check it?

Comment: I'd recommend you to upgrade the RStudio IDE. The Pandoc version in your RStudio seems to be older than 1.15.2.

Comment: Thanks for that - problem solved.